# How to make sure each Activity can only have 1 "child activity" at a time

Tags: android, android-intent

#### What I want to do:

1) Prevent an activity from creating duplicate child activities of the same type
   (e.g. `Activity A` starts 2x `Activity B` if user taps `"start B"` rapidly)

2) Prevent an activity from creating more than 1 activity at a time
   (e.g. `Activity A` starts 1x `Activity B` and 1x `Activity C` if user taps `"start B"` followed by `"start C"` rapidly)

#### What I currently have:

(Activity A) can start (Activity B) and (Activity C).
(Activity B) can start (Activity D).
(Activity C) can start nothing.
(Activity D) can start nothing.

Each activity has 1 button for each activity that it can start. For example (Activity A) has 2 buttons.

Each button is attached to an event listener as follows

```
buttonStartB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
     Intent myIntent = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
     myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); // to achieve property (1)
     startActivityForResult(myIntent, SOME_CONSTANT_REQUEST_CODE_VALUE);

     // don't know how to achieve property (2)???
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, we are talking about some split second before the next `Activity` is launched. So I'd use one of the following two options:

**Option 1**:
Disable all the UI elements (e.g. `Button`s) from which you do not wish to accept further input. Re-enable them after a certain delay, for example using [`Handler#postDelayed()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable,%20long))

The problem with this approach is that Buttons flickering from "enabled" to "disabled" and back may look bad. So instead of disabling the UI elements there is ...

**Option 2**: Use a `boolean enabled = true;` and toggle it once the first `Button` is clicked. Check the value in `onClick()` and only process the click if `enabled == true`. Reset the value to `true` using a `Handler` like above.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have already considered the above. I was hoping for a solution that involved some combination of different Activity flags. as I felt that **Option 2** lead to undesirable semantic uncoupling as well as just feeling less "robust"

Comment: @AlanSTACK - if "less robust" means that there might be a slim chance of the user starting a second Activity then I think the approach using Intent flags may be more unreliable: the new Activity is not started as part of the execution of onClick(), it's only scheduled for starting in the main thread queue. So basically the undesired click event might take place and its onClick() might be executed before the "old" activity is removed from the screen.

Comment: Wouldn't a flag that kills all children activities guarantee meeting `property (2)`? (e.i. a flag that kills all children activities of the current activity - that is in the process of launching a new child activity)? Does such a flag exist?

Comment: @AlanSTACK - the only flag of which I know and which would kill all sibling `Activity`s is `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK`. Unfortunately this would also remove the parent `Activity` so using it together with `startActivityForResult()` would not make much sense. List of [Intent flags related to Activity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setFlags(int))